# Type error, cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript

i got stuck in the Javascript code below, I don't know what's the problem.
the code is always showing"Type error, cannot read property 'match' of undefined",
Here IS THE CODE:

```
function keepletteronly(str) {
     str=str.toLowerCase();//Make the string to lower case
     arr=str.split("");    //This way I make an array out of the string
     arr1=[]; //make an new array
for (i=1; i<=arr.length;i++){
    if (arr[i].match(/[a-z]/)!=null) {  //This is where the problem is
        arr1.push(arr[i]); //retain only the letters and append to the arr1
    }
}
newstring=arr1.join;
return newstring;  


}



keepletteronly("1eye");
```

Comment: `i` should be 0 and the condition should be `<` not `<=`.

Comment: you are right, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The index of a JS array starts from zero.
You should change your for sentence to

```
for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
```

Moreover, another sentence is also incorrect:

```
newstring=arr1.join;
```

it should be

```
newstring=arr1.join('');
```

or simply produce the resultant string without arr1, like:

```
newstring='';
...
newstring+=arr[i];
```

Comment: I tried but it still wouldn't work, same error popped up

Comment: Wow, NOW it works! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are base 0, meaning the first item is at index `0`. Imagine you have three items in an array, the `length` property will say `3` and the three items will occupy indices `0`, `1` and `2`.

In your `for` loop, you start at index `1` (`i=1;`), meaning the loop will skip the first item (at index `0`) and then you iterate while `i` is lower **or equal** to the length of the array. The length of the array is `3`, but because of base 0, the last item in the array is at index `2`. So in the last iteration of your `for` loop, you try to access index `3` of the array, which is `undefined`.

So, what you need to do is to change your `for` loop expressions to look like this:

```
(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

This way you will properly iterate over `0`, `1` and `2` instead of `1`, `2` and `3`

Comment: I tried but it still wouldn't work, thank you though

Comment: Thanks , now it works!